Label and Input not aligned with roboto regular
I have some trouble aligning my input and label, using chrome as browser. I use both a Retina screen and a non-Retina screen, but I can’t achieve a perfect result on both. It looks like Roboto Regular doesn’t render the same inside <label> and <input>.
This problem looks pretty inconsistent. I did a tiny example locally, if I add <h3> title before <label>and <input>, alignment is correct, if I don't have these <h3>title, I have an alignment problem.
Here is the result :

Here is an example to reproduce the problem :


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" integrity="sha512-NhSC1YmyruXifcj/KFRWoC561YpHpc5Jtzgvbuzx5VozKpWvQ+4nXhPdFgmx8xqexRcpAglTj9sIBWINXa8x5w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .field {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 5px 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    input, select, label {
            font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      font-size:14.4px;
      height: 30px;
        }

    label {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }
      
    .line {
      position: fixed;
      height:1px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      left:0;
      top: 75px;
      z-index:1;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Titre :</label>
        <input type="text" value="Titre">
    </div>
</body>

</html>



My label and input are vertically aligned.
I have a line-height fixed to 1.15px by the lib normalize.css.
If I use another font like Arial, I do not have the problem anymore.
I’m a bit confused. Why is the font render different between <label> and my <input> with the same font, same line-height, same height ? Is it due to carret inside input ?
First solution
I used line-height: normal; on my label and it looks fine. But that’s not a solution for everyone and won’t display the same line-height on all browsers.
Second solution : C3roe Solution
Remove the height as @C3roe comment says. If I want to preserve a similar height, I can use a padding to do it. But I don't like this solution too, cause if I want a 30px height input precisely, it doesn't work.
Third solution
Use display: table-cell instead of display: flex.
.field {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
}

Also, I recommend this article to have a deep understanding of how it is difficult to center a font properly.

A proper [mre] of your issue still belongs directly into the question, please do not just refer us to external platforms such as codepen.

The issue seems to disappear, as soon as the height:30px you applied to both the label and the input field, is removed.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@C3roe, can I use a lib and a specific font with code snippet on stackoverflow ?
